# rails migration setting boolean field doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a migration which adds a boolean column and sets value for some of the rows. The new value doesn't get saved to the database when the model is saved. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
class AddSmartToStudent
  def change
    add_column :students, :smart, :boolean

    Student.where(grade: 'A').each do |student|
      student.smart = true
      student.save!
    end
   end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run `rails db:migrate` and got any errors?

Comment: Yes I am running migrate and there are no errors. This works when type is not boolean. It just doesn't work with boolean.

Comment: What’s your database?

Comment: can you update the question with current attributes of `students table`

Answer (score 2):

In your migration, you add a boolean column, and right after that use it in the model. Not sure it is possible - when migration is not ended yet the transaction is not committed. The `Student` model might not have `smart` field yet.

As Luis Silva suggests you could use `reset_column_information` method to refresh info about columns for `Student`. But the problem is migrations are not for manipulating with data. If you want to change some data it's better to do in a `rake` task.

If for some reason you HAVE TO do it in migration, you can do it in plain SQL query. For PostgreSQL it will be:

```
execute "UPDATE students SET smart='t' WHERE grade='A'"
```

Comment: Listen to Ilya this guy is awesome!

Comment: @NickM I didn’t know I have fans here TOO :)

Comment: Yeah well I have a few pints set aside if you make it to London at some point!

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the cached information about columns, which will cause them to be reloaded on the next request.

Execute this line before your clause where

`Student.reset_column_information`

[reset_column_information](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/reset_column_information)

Comment: Didn't work. I am guessing it has to do with some caveats with  boolean type as it works fine with other types.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that are clear to me right of the bet.

1. As stated by others you're trying to use an attribute that you add in that same migration. The safe thing to do is to reset the column information like explained in the [answer of Luis Silva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032222/3982562).
2. The second issue has to do with the fact that you use `def change` where some of the content isn't reversible. Everything in the change method should be reversible. Otherwise `def up` and `def down` should be used.

Here are two options that might solve your issue:

1. Using `def up` and `def down`.

   ```
   class AddSmartToStudent
     def up
       add_column :students, :smart, :boolean

       Student.reset_column_information
       Student
         .where(grade: 'A')
         .find_each { |student| student.update!(smart: true) }
     end

     def down
       remove_column :students, :smart
     end
   end
   ```
2. Using [`reversible`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#method-i-reversible).

   ```
   class AddSmartToStudent
     def change
       add_column :students, :smart, :boolean

       reversible do |change|
         change.up do
           Student.reset_column_information
           Student
             .where(grade: 'A')
             .find_each { |student| student.update!(smart: true) }
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```

If you don't care about Rails callbacks, validations, etc. you could also use

```
Student.where(grade: 'A').update_all(smart: true)
```

as replacement for

```
Student.where(grade: 'A').find_each { |student| student.update!(smart: true) }
```

This updates all the records with a single query but doesn't instantiate the records, meaning Rails callbacks, validations, etc. won't run. For more info see [`update_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all).